# translation only work us other not working for other locale in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, localisation

admin panel always do translation from `en_US`. where did i do wrong?

helper

```
$helper=Mage::helper('test');
$helper->__('Shipping Method');
```

**config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <test>
                <files>
                    <default>test_test.csv</default>
                </files>
            </test>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <test>
                <files>
                    <default>test_test.csv</default>
                </files>
            </test>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

**app/locale/en_US/test_test.csv**

```
"Shipping address","Shipping Address"
"Billing address","Billing Address"
"Shipping Method","Shipping Method"
```

**app/locale/ar_SA/test_test.csv**

```
"Shipping address","test"
"Billing address","test1"
"Shipping Method","test2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I reckon the tag between `<modules>` and `<files>` should be the entire module name with the vendor name, in your case it seems to only be the module name.

So if your module is `Test_Test` I reckon your `config.xml` code should be:

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Test_Test>
                <files>
                    <default>test_test.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Test_Test>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Test_Test>
                <files>
                    <default>test_test.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Test_Test>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: it is working for other place but in helper it is still calling `en_US`