# how to get current local translation in helper

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

i am trying to get translation from my current locale in `admin panel`but alway get the `en_Us` translation. how to get current locale translation.

```
$helper=Mage::helper('test');
$helper->__('Shipping address');
```

for admin translation

```
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
            <modules>
                <test>
                    <files>
                        <default>test_test.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </test>
            </modules>
    </translate>
<adminhtml>
```

Comment: Does your module define its own translations in **adminhtml** scope?

Comment: yes added the xml code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [translation only work us other not working for other locale in custom module](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111304/translation-only-work-us-other-not-working-for-other-locale-in-custom-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
            <modules>
                <test>     <-----------------------------+
                    <files>                              |
                        <default>test_test.csv</default> |
                    </files>                             |
                </test>     <----------------------------+
            </modules>                                   |
    </translate>                                         |
<adminhtml>                                              |
                                                         |
                                                         |
```

"test" should be "Test_Test" or whatever your actual module name is, not the helper alias

Comment: Haha yeah I said the same thing yesterday: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111306/2380